# About irrationality measure.

Tags: irrationality-measure

The irrationality measure of $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $\displaystyle\mu(\alpha)=\inf\left\{\nu\in\mathbb{R}_+,\; \text{card}\left(\left\{\frac pq\in\mathbb{Q},\; 0<\left|\alpha-\frac pq\right|<\frac 1{q^\nu}\right\}\right)<+\infty\right\}$.

If $\mu(\alpha)=2$, it seems to me that $\inf$ is not $\min$ because of Dirichlet's theorem (which states that for every irrational number $\alpha$ there exist infinitely many integers $p,q$ such that
$\displaystyle 0<\left|\alpha-\frac pq\right|<\frac 1{q^2}$).

My questions are :

- do you know some (irrational) numbers $\alpha$ for which $\mu(\alpha)\in[2,+\infty]$ is known to be a $\min$ ?
- do you know some (irrational) numbers $\alpha$ for which $\mu(\alpha)\in[2,+\infty]$ is known to be a $\inf$ but not a $\min$ ?

Many thanks.

Comment: There are numerous possible symbols to choose as variables. Therefore there is absolutely no reason to use the exact same symbol to represent two different things within a single equation. Even though one is only a dummy variable, this is a very poor practice that I have seen cause endless headaches to those who fail to recognize that the two uses represent different things.

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Comment: There's a close relation between irrationality measure of $\alpha$ and size of the partial quotients in the continued fraction of $\alpha$. Using that I think you can answer both your questions.

Comment: I've heard that the [most irrational of all numbers is the golden ratio $\phi$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaasbfdJdJg). So that would be a good choice to investigate.

Comment: Are you following up on my comment, P.F?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have tried to work about it but I don't see clearly the link between my question and your remark...